# knowing which div was the target for Sortable.js

Tags: sortablejs

in a list of 10 li elements, I'm sorting the list via Sortable.js. But I need the id of the item the dragged li was dropped on. How would I get that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SortableJs to sort items within the same category list but also to be able to move items from one category list to another and vice versa.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but this is the way I get the ID of the destination container(list).

- `event.oldIndex` is the original position of the item.
- `event.from` is the original container element of the item (e.g `ul` tag)
- `event.newIndex` is the final position of the item.
- `event.to` is the final container element of the item (e.g. `ul` tag)

Whit that said you can do something like this:

```js
/* If position did not change neither the containing list */
if (event.oldIndex === event.newIndex && event.from === event.to) { return; }

/* If position changed within the same category */
if (event.oldIndex !== event.newIndex) {
  const newPosition = event.newIndex
}

/* If product was moved to another category list */
if (event.from !== event.to) {
  /* Accessing `<ul data-id="10">` */
  const categoryId = event.to.dataset.id;
  /* Accessing `<ul id="list_on_the_right_11">` */
  const elementId = event.to.id;
}
```

Hope it could be helpful in some way.